Unable to compile 2 clients with Chillicream's StrawberryShake
I use StrawberryShake 13.9 in ASP.NET Core 8 / C# and want to consume 2 graphql API from 2 different services which I created with Chillicream's excellent HotChocolate workflow.
At client side I have 2 different folders with different *.graphq files and each folder an own '.graphqlrc.json' file.
To receive the schemas from APIs I do calls like dotnet graphql init [...] . This works well, twice schema.graphql and schema.extensions.graphql are generated in their separate folders.
WHEN I compile it generates both clients ClientX.cs and ClientsY.cs with lots of errors. Compiler complains about double definitions and ambiguities in the clients " like: DbClientX.Client.cs(2089, 26): [CS8646] "IStringOperationFilterInputInfo.IsAndSet" ist mehrfach explizit implementiert. or missing implementations like: DbClientX.Client.cs(1283, 52): [CS0535] "IntOperationFilterInput" implementiert den Schnittstellenmember "IIntOperationFilterInputInfo.IsNltSet" nicht.
The behavior does not happen, if queries don't use filtering + sorting.
Another idea was to bring it to different namespaces but in '.graphqlrc.json' the namespace line "namespace": "Some.Space.ServiceX", does not bring anything at all, the tools absolutely ignore this line (or I didn't understand the meaning of it).
Is someone who is able to use 2 services (queries with filtering, sorting etc.) in one client-app with Chillicream's tools?
Thanks
Most of all attempts were to modify the graphql-config file, but no results.

In order to generate multiple GraphQL clients in the same project using Strawberry Shake, you will need to do the following:

Create a separate directory for each GQL service
Generate the client for each service in their respective directories (with unique names)
Update the .graphqlrc.json file for each service, and add a unique namespace for each client

Example
Assume you want to call two GraphQL services, WidgetService and SprocketService.

> mkdir ./WidgetService
> cd WidgetService
> dotnet graphql init https://widgets/graphql -n WidgetClient -p ./
> cd ../
> mkdir ./SprocketService
> cd SprocketService
> dotnet graphql init https://sprockets/graphql -n SprocketClient -p ./

Edit ./WidgetService/.graphqlrc.json
{
  "schema": "schema.graphql",
  "documents": "**/*.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "strawberryShake": {
      "name": "WidgetClient",
      "namespace": "Widgets",                    <-- add this line
      "url": "https://widgets/graphql",
      "records": {
        "inputs": false,
        "entities": false
      },
      "transportProfiles": [
        {
          "default": "Http",
          "subscription": "WebSocket"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Edit ./SprocketService/.graphqlrc.json
{
  "schema": "schema.graphql",
  "documents": "**/*.graphql",
  "extensions": {
    "strawberryShake": {
      "name": "SprocketClient",
      "namespace": "Sprockets",                    <-- add this line
      "url": "https://sprockets/graphql",
      "records": {
        "inputs": false,
        "entities": false
      },
      "transportProfiles": [
        {
          "default": "Http",
          "subscription": "WebSocket"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


This works, great @Shaddy

Using two different namespaces should do it. You may need to manually delete the obj folder to ensure new files are generated with the namespaces you provided in the .graphqlrc.json file.

Finally I made it work. The fault was to not modify correctly the .graphqlrc.json files in both steps; spefically the "namespace" line.
Thankx @ bryar1991

Please don't add "thanks" as an answer.  Instead, accept the answer that worked for you.  Thanks!

what steps are you referring to here? cc @dbc

could you explain how you fixed it?
